# Scope variable for directive is undefined in constructor when using bindToController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

So I've got a directive which should take a value when created. Let's call the directive `MyDirective`. To use it and pass a value to it you can do like this:

```
<my-directive value="'I will be undefined'"></my-directive>
```

I'm using TypeScript so I want to have classes without `$scope`, so for that I bind to controller.

```
class MyDirectiveController {
    public value:string;

    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {
        // I wanna do something with this.value at this point
        // But it is undefined ...
        console.log(this.value);

        $scope.$watch('value', this.valueDidChangeCallback).bind(this);

    }

    valueDidChangeCallback:any = () => {
        // Now I can do the thing I wanted to do ...
        console.log(this.value);
    };
}

export class MyDirectiveDirective {
    restrict: string = 'E';
    templateUrl: string = 'my-directive.html';
    bindToController: boolean = true;
    controllerAs: string = 'vm';
    scope:any = {
        'value': '='
    };

    controller: any = ($scope: ng.IScope) => new MyDirectiveController($scope);

    constructor() {}

    static Factory(): ng.IDirective {
        return new LicenseOverviewPageDirective();
    }
}
```

So the problem is that I need to use `$watch` because the value passed to the directive ("I will be undefined") will not yet be set when in the constructor (where I need it ...)

Is there a better way to do this without watch?

Comment: I think you are confusing `controllerAs` with `bindToController`. ControllerAs  just assigns the controller to the scope as a variable. Where as, bindToController will use the controller as the scope. So that `this === $scope` is true.

Comment: That might be, I'm just trying to use classes withouth the `$scope` variable  and pass a value to the directive which I can use without having a watch, any idea if that can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VOS2jUaBKSzBI3Fje79V?p=preview)

I just adjusted your code a bit - and it is working:

```
namespace MyNamespace { 

    export class MyDirectiveController {
        public value:string;    
        static $inject = ['$scope'];

        constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {
            // I wanna do something with this.value at this point
            // NOW It is defined
            console.log(this.value);
            $scope.$watch('value', this.valueDidChangeCallback).bind(this);
        }

        valueDidChangeCallback:any = () => {        
            // Now I can do the thing I wanted to do ...
            console.log(this.value);
        };
      }

    export class MyDirectiveDirective {
        restrict: string = 'E';
        templateUrl: string = 'my-directive.html';
          controller = MyNamespace.MyDirectiveController;
          controllerAs: string = 'vm';
        bindToController: boolean = true;    
        scope:any = {
            'value': '='
        };
      }

    angular
       .module('MyApp')
       .directive('myDirective', [() => {return new MyNamespace.MyDirectiveDirective()}])
}
```

Comment: Great to see that! Enjoy Typescript with Angular ;)