# Not able to access custom factory inside a directive in angular typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i have injected storageService but i tried to access in the link function using this.storageService its giving undefined.

Can any one help me on this ?

```
module App.Directive {
  import Services = Core.Services;
  import Shared = Core.Shared;
  export class UserNav implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = 'A';
    require: any = "^?ngModel";
    scope = true;
    templateUrl: any = "template/user-nav.html";
    link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel: any) {
        var a = this.storageService.getItem("userInfo", false);
        console.log("getting > " + a);
    }
    constructor(public routerService: Services.RouterService,
        public storageService: Services.StorageService) {
    }
    static factory(): any {
        var directive = (routerService: Services.RouterService,
            storageService: Services.StorageService) => {
            return new UserNav(routerService, storageService);
        }
        directive['$inject'] = ['routerService', 'storageService'];
        return directive;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a [way how directive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33322282/1679310) could be created with an example and few links

Answer (score 0):

<strike>So the problem is that the link function
Change:</strike>

```
module App.Directive {
  import Services = Core.Services;
  import Shared = Core.Shared;
  export class UserNav implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = 'A';
    require: any = "^?ngModel";
    scope = true;
    templateUrl: any = "template/user-nav.html";
    link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel: any) {
        var a = this.storageService.getItem("userInfo", false);
        console.log("getting > " + a);
    }
    constructor(public routerService: Services.RouterService,
        public storageService: Services.StorageService) {
    }
    static factory(): any {
        var directive = (routerService: Services.RouterService,
            storageService: Services.StorageService) => {
            return new UserNav(routerService, storageService);
        }
        directive['$inject'] = ['routerService', 'storageService'];
        return directive;
    }
  }
}
```

To:

```
module App.Directive {
  import Services = Core.Services;
  import Shared = Core.Shared;
  export class UserNav implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = 'A';
    require: any = "^?ngModel";
    scope = true;
    templateUrl: any = "template/user-nav.html";
    link(scope, element, attributes, ngModel: any) {
        var a = this.storageService.getItem("userInfo", false);
        console.log("getting > " + a);
    }
    constructor(public routerService: Services.RouterService,
        public storageService: Services.StorageService) {
    }
    static factory(): any {
        var directive = (routerService: Services.RouterService,
            storageService: Services.StorageService) => {
            return new UserNav(routerService, storageService);
        }
        directive['$inject'] = ['routerService', 'storageService'];
        return directive;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: The above answer won't work. Because the link function is used as a callback and `this` is the global object. You'd have to set the services as a variable inside your module, then you'd have access to it through scope. [see my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rauluccocm/u3sezfmu/)

Comment: Its not working.    Its show the following error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined

Comment: @KiranGopal That's right, I updated the answer and added a link to a fiddle with my proposal