# Using $scope and 'this' in the controller with Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-controller

Regarding `$scope` and `this` when using ui-router,

If I am using the `controllerAs` syntax, ie:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app.login', {
            url: '/login',                  
            templateUrl: 'modules/login/login.html',
            controllerAs: 'login',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            data: {
                authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
            }
        });
}])
```

In my controller then, I'm using `this` instead of `$scope`. So I have code like this in my login controller:

```
this.func1 = func1;
this.func2 = func2;
this.message = "Hello world!";
```

But I'm also using `$scope` to listen to globally broadcasted events from my `$rootScope`, because if I remember correctly, `this` doesn't have methods belonging to `$scope`, even though they are being interchanged.

```
$scope.$on('event', handler);
```

So I'm listening to an event broadcast by `$rootScope` and calling some other controller logic, like `func2`, when this event is broadcasted:

```
$scope.$on('auth-login-failed', function(event) {
// call some other function in controller
});
```

What if I wanted to call `func2` inside the `$on` handler? Should I do some convention where I initialize something like this in my controller?

```
var that = this;

$scope.$on('auth-login-failed', function(event) {
    this.func2();
});
```

I'm just curious on the best way to proceed and what the general convention is here. Is it proper to use both `$scope` and `this`, and what are the main differences between the two, since they can be interchanged?

Comment: there are multiple articles that describe the differences in detail here already.... essentially, $scope *always* exists, and using ControllerAs creates the controller as a property on $scope.  As for referring to the controller inside callbacks, using an alias or using `.bind()` are both viable, and are more of an issue with JavaScript closures than with angular itself.  ***technically***, you could refer to `$scope.login.func2()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion, too keep the logical context in some variable - is really good, and good practice:

```
var _this = this;

$scope.$on('auth-login-failed', function(event) {
    _this.func2();
});
```

In fact, that is the way how **`Typescript`** is doing the same, behind the scene for us. It is called

#### [Arrow function](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/arrow-functions.md)

and will look like this in typescript:

```
$scope.$on('auth-login-failed', (event) => {
    this.func2();
});
```

becuase Typescript compiler behind the scene will do the above trick with logical scope being kept in some variable.

I would suggest to you:

> ... do the best to start to use Typescript. *It is the future of the angular worlds anyway...*

There are some links to some details how to create angular's `controller` in `Typescript`, including **working examples**

- [How can I define my controller using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30482138/1679310)
- [How To bind data using TypeScript Controller & Angular Js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30501735/1679310)
- [Scope variable for directive is undefined in constructor when using bindToController](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32993497/1679310)